# Android Studio local Subversion server

Tags: android-studio, svn, local

I'm running latest MacOS and Android Studio versions.
I've looked online for help regarding local SVN for Android Studio and all the tutorials gave me an online server option.

I didn't find what I was looking for. I did use file:///... for SVN URL, but it keeps asking me for authentication and my password isn't working. I'm thinking that some plugin is required, like in Eclipse (I had a local SVN in for my Eclipse workspace) or installing beforehand a SVN server.

But I would like a local SVN for my workspace in Android Studio.

How should it work?

Best regards.

Comment: How did you create the local repository? Could you add this information?

Comment: Thank for trying to help. I installed a SVN server on a Ubuntu remote server and I managed to connect to it. I will use that one. Thank you.